# Get a new computer or Graphics card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics

I have a Dell Precision Workstation 670, all was working fine under Windows XP.

After the second unfortunate system failure and subsequent system scramble, the system was rebuilt with Windows 7 64-bit.  It seems that now the graphics is VERY VERY slow.  The system contains the latest update of the NVIDIA driver for the FX3400/4400 card.

Question: To improve things and limp along a little longer, should the graphics card only be replaced?  Or is it better to simply replace the system and move on.

EDIT: I have a 670 not a 650 as was originally stated.

Comment: What's the graphics card slot? AGP? PCIe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it. The chipset is only supposed to support AGP Video, so even if it has a PCI slot you will be suffering on how well the computer can actually use the card. And based on the general specs of the 650, not much money could buy you a much better system.

Comment: MaskedPlant is right, the system is really old (early 2000's). You are probably having problems because the Aero Desktop. Your video card is most likely culprit, but it would be better to get a new system. The general rule of thumb is to replace your machine every 4 to 6 years.